Updating textarea value in React
How can I update textarea value in React? I used the setState hook on a button to the textarea's value, but then I can't edit the content of the textarea, and when I use defaultValue instead of value or add an onChange attribute to the textarea, the setState hook doesn't work and the browser console throws me two warnings (which I will show below).

This is the warnings I get from the browser console, not sure why this happened. Also, if I only use setState to the textarea's value, it works properly, but as mentioned before I cannot edit the content of the textarea without changing the value property to defaultValue or add onChange to the textarea.
Edit:
The whole file's code:
"use client";

import { Button } from "@mui/material";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function TextAreaCreate() {
const [content, setContent] = useState("<p></p><br/>")

function paragraph() {
    setContent(content + "\n<p></p>")
}
function handlechange(event: any) {
    setContent(event.target.content)
}

return (
    <div>
        <textarea name="content" className="text-black border border-black w-full h-52" value={content} onChange={handlechange} required></textarea><br />
        <div className="m-5">
            <Button variant="contained" onClick={paragraph}>Paragraph</Button>
        </div>
    </div>
)

}

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I'd share the code rather than console warnings. But here's what I presume. You need to pass onChange.
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState(''); // here's your state

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setText(event.target.value); // you update the state as the user types
  };

  const updateText = () => {
    setText('Updated Text'); // here you set a new value when a button is clicked
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <textarea
        value={text} // Controlled component
        onChange={handleChange} // you update state on change
      />
      <button onClick={updateText}>Update Text</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


If you provide a value prop without onChange, the textarea becomes read-only, which is why you couldn’t edit the content.
